# Add <p> tags programatically in Java

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I have a HTML code like this :

```
<p> This is paragraph 1 </p>
This is paragraph 2
<p> This is paragraph 3 </p>
```

I will process the above HTML in Java and I wanted the processed HTML to be :

```
<p> This is paragraph 1 </p>
<p> This is paragraph 2 </p>
<p> This is paragraph 3 </p>
```

And there might be big paragraphs with more than one line. Therefore, line by line processing doesn't work in this case. For example,

```
<p> ...
...
...
</p>
```

And there can be cases like,

```
<p> This </p> can be <p> the case too. </p>
```

I need the above line to be converted to :

```
<p> This </p><p> can be </p><p> the case too. </p>
```

I want to achieve this because Jsoup doesn't identify text without < p > tags. If Jsoup can do that by any means, I am happy with that too. I don't want any text to be missed out from the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSoup can give you the parts which are not in `<P>`. Since they are not enclosed in a tag, they are *text nodes* rather than elements. So you should traverse the nodes rather than elements. Here is an example:

```
public class SimpleTest {

    public static final String HTML = "<p> This is paragraph 1 </p>\n"
                                    + "This is paragraph 2\n"
                                    + "<p> This is paragraph 3 </p>";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(HTML);

        List<Node> nodes = doc.body().childNodes();

        for ( Node node : nodes ) {
            System.out.printf("Node of %s, %s%n", node.getClass(), node);
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Node of class org.jsoup.nodes.Element, <p> This is paragraph 1 </p>
Node of class org.jsoup.nodes.TextNode,  This is paragraph 2 
Node of class org.jsoup.nodes.Element, <p> This is paragraph 3 </p>
```

So when you want to do something practical with an unknown node, you should test it with `instanceof` to see if it's a `TextNode`, an `Element` or something else. Then you cast it to the relevant class, and you can use all its methods in addition to the ones that are available in `Node`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried writing a parser to check if there's a p tag at the beginning of each line?

Code could look something like that:

```
String[] splitted = html_code.split("\n");
String solution="";
for(String s : splitted){
    s = s.trim();
    if(s.startsWith("<p>"){
        solution+=s;
    }else{
        solution = "<p>"+s+"</p>;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is a valid solution. But I can't be so sure if the new paragraph always starts from the new line.

Comment: Do you have example data? If it doesn't always start at the beginning, how should you know where to put the p tag?

Comment: Edited the question. Have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Cool, I figured it out with RealSkeptic's help. This is just the improved version of the code appropriate for the question :

```
for( Node node : nodes ) {
       if( node.getClass() == Element.class ) {
           Element element = (Element) node; 
           System.out.println( element.tag() + " " + element.text() );
       }
       else if( node.getClass() == TextNode.class && ! node.toString().trim().isEmpty() )
           System.out.println( node.toString().trim() );
}
```

Here I checked node isEmpty because Jsoup considers each line as a TextNode.